# Few questions regarding Salesforce task functionality

Tags: tasks, event

1) Is there any way to show scheduled task in calendar like event?

2) What are difference between task owner and who? Task is always assigned to owner than when do we set whoId?

3) Task owner can be a user and calendar. What does this Calendar mean?

Answer (score 2):

1) you should vote up this idea.  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ky93AAA

2) WhoID refers to people.  ID of a related Contact or Lead. If the WhoId refers to a lead, then the WhatId field must be empty. The owner determines who owns the record.

3) Use a public calendar to manage group activities. For example, track a group’s events, such as marketing events, product releases, or training classes, or schedule a common activity, such as a team vacation. Use a resource calendar to schedule the use of a shared resource, such as a conference room or an overhead projector.